# Replacing existing RPubs document with a newer version

Tags: r-markdown

Is it possible to `replace/overwrite` my markdown document in the `RPubs`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think there is a direct way to update a file. But this is what you can do:

You can delete the file and upload a new one and insert the same slug during the upldoad. If you do this, the url of the file wont change.

Answer (score 7):

There is a option of republish once you select the option Knit to HTML for the same file once again. In that, it has option Update Existing. If its selected file gets updated without the URL being changed.

Comment: oski86, please change this to be the accepted solution. I can confirm that the described method does indeed work in RStudio. If one tries to directly use the 'Publish' action, the button to the upper right of the script subwindow holding the MarkDown, one gets a dialog box with the option "Update Existing". But this actually doesn't change anything. As @Fuaad describes, one **must** knit to HTML, and **then** in the resulting window with HTML use the "Republish" button - the same dialog about "Update Existing" pops up, but this time it actually works.

Comment: I opened an issue over at RStudio's [github repo](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/7594), so anyone stumbling across this SO thread in the future can try having a look there for any updates regarding this issue.