# Updating existing report in rPubs

Tags: r

Is there any way to update existing published file in rpubs?

I know the following function can update recently published file(by recently I mean the current session) by using the 'id' parameter:

> rpubsUpload(title, htmlFile, id = NULL, properties = list(), 
>       method = getOption("rpubs.upload.method", "auto"))

But my question is, is there a way to update a published file that was published 1 year ago?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is similar to the following question:

[Replacing existing RPubs document with a newer version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571785/replacing-existing-rpubs-document-with-a-newer-version)

Recap: you can't update your publication, but you can delete it and upload a new version using the same slug.

Answer (score 1):

If using Rstudio, select the option Knit to HTML for the same file once again, then click on republish button.

[image]